# How to verify a list of objects is empty?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a list of objects that need to check if its empty or not, but I all the followings returns nullpointer exception.

```
List <MyClass> mylist;

mylist.isEmpty
mylist.equal(null)
```

Comment: have a look at [CollectionUtils.isEmpty()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections//javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#isEmpty(java.util.Collection)) from commons collections

Comment: In addition to the answers you can also check for mylist.size()>0 to know if your list is empty or not.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have not initialized the `List <MyClass> mylist` itself. Currently it refers to a `null` reference. Trying to invoke any method on `null` reference will be a `NullPointerException`. You can use a `null` check before calling `isEmpty()` on it , like this :

```
if(mylist!=null && !mylist.isEmpty()) {
 // mylist is not empty
}
```

You can also use Apache's [CollectionUtils#isNotEmpty()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/index.html)

> Null-safe check if the specified collection is not empty.
>
> **Null returns false.**

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing the `myList` before calling the methods.

You need to initialize it first. For example

```
List <MyClass> mylist = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
myList.add(first);
myList.add(second);
```

now you can call

```
mylist.isEmpty
mylist.equal(null)
```

Answer (score 1):

you must `new` your list.

```
 List <MyClass> mylist = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

now check:

```
 boolean b = (mylist!=null) ? false : mylist.isEmpty();
```